# SAML Authentication Portal

Tags: php, open-source, saml

I'd like to develop a portal similar to what a company like OneLogin (http://www.onelogin.com/) has: The user would login with their login credentials then have links to the web resources that their account is associated with. When they see their resources all they need to do is click on them and they'll be automatically login in (SAML authentication).

Are there any open source projects out there that have started on this effort? It would be great if there was something that we could use as a base to build on top of with a friendly license (e.g. MIT).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged it "php" but that doesn't appear in your question?

Essentially, you need a client-side SAML stack.

I've listed all the ones I know about here:

[SAML : A SAML stack](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-stack.html) .

In terms of php, have a look at [simplesamlPHP](http://simplesamlphp.org/).

That has all the plumbing you'll need and it's open source.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it developed with Symfony2 PHP framework you could check [SamlSPBundle](https://github.com/aerialship/SamlSPBundle/) or its foundation stand-alone library [lightsaml](https://github.com/aerialship/lightsaml)